# ROS Answers SE migration: pid controller

Tags: ros, pid, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
Im trying to implement my own pid controller os a simple joint.
my difficulty is to understand how to build it using srv/topics/actionlib etc,
and how to get a continuous action that will evantually stop the joint at the right position.

thanks,
Nir.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44420/pid-controller/) by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pr2_controller_manager provides a hard realtime loop to control the robot mechanism. The robot mechanism is represented by a set of effort controlled joints. I really tried this and it is a really great tool. Dont think that it is only for pr2. Here some useful links to check out

[concept of controller manager](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_manager)

[writing real time controller](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)

[implementing pid with control toolbox and pr2 controller](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20PID%20to%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)

hope these help

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [itfanr](https://answers.ros.org/users/34867/itfanr/) on 2018-09-14**:
You can refer to this repo to write a controller:

https://github.com/epfl-lasa/kuka-lwr-ros

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a fairly generic PID server that you can get from [here](https://github.com/tdenewiler/pid_server.git). For a joint you could start a few PID servers - one for position/angle/velocity. The nice thing to do is use rxplot to visualize your desired vs. actual joint angle, use dynamic reconfigure to modify your PID gains during runtime, and tune those gains based on how well the PID loop is performing.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6